# Injecting Function in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I try to inject a function inside my plugin

plugin.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import mediumZoom from 'medium-zoom'

Vue.prototype.$mediumZoom = mediumZoom()
```

When I try to load my page it keeps loading infinite and the page in the end doesnt react, it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are calling `mediumZoom` on page load. You probably want:

```
Vue.prototype.$mediumZoom = mediumZoom
// don't call function, no () here ---^
```